# Is there a way to get MarketingCloudSDK-iOS from Carthage?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sdk

We need to implement MarketingCloud for our native iOS app and we are currently using Carthage to manage our dependencies. Is Salesforce MarketingCloud supporting this? I cannot find the info anywhere.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the SDK does not support Carthage. You can use Cocoapods or pull it in manually.